# Unity cannot access TextMeshPro when using delegate event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am calling a method using delegate event which works fine. However in the method thats get called I am trying to change the text of TextMeshPro text. Unfortunatly nothing happens.

I can change the text in another other methods or if I call the method directly. By ass soon as the method gets called through and event call then nothing.

I don't get any error. Even I loop over the `MatchCode` TextMeshPro object to list all the components I also get nothing

```
using DarkRift.Client;
using System.Net;
using System;
using DarkRift;
using Scripts.Models;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Scripts.Networking {

    public class NetworkingManager
    {

        private static NetworkingManager instance;
        public bool GotMatch = false;

        private DarkRiftClient client;

        public delegate void MatchCreatedEvent(int matchId);
        public static event MatchCreatedEvent OnMatchCreated;

        public void ChangeText () {
            matchID = 12345;
            OnMatchCreated?.Invoke(matchID);
        }
}
```

And in the NameForm script where I have the `MatchCodeReceived` method

```
using Scripts.Networking;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NameForm : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TMPro.TMP_InputField InputNameField;
    public TMPro.TMP_InputField InputMatchId;
    public TMPro.TMP_Text MatchCode;

    private bool IsSubmiting = false;
    private bool LoadingScene = false;

    public delegate void MatchCodeEvent(int matchId);
    public static event MatchCodeEvent OnMatchCodeReceived;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        NetworkingManager.OnMatchCreated += MatchCodeReceived;

        if (InputNameField == null) {
            throw new System.Exception("missing input field");
        }
        if (InputMatchId == null)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("missing input field");
        }
    }

    public void MatchCodeReceived (int MatchId)
    {
        //Debug.Log("MatchCodeReceived: " + MatchId);
        MatchCode.text = MatchId.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is ChangeText() being called?  I tested what you have above by itself and the text changes as expected from the event.

Comment: The `ChangeText()` is being called from a Darkrift server response. This all works ok. I can add any other code into `MatchCodeReceived()` such as `Debug.log` which is working. I have the same issue when I add the legacy UI text as well. Seems like a problem accessing GameObjects maybe? If I call `MatchCodeReceived` from the `start()` the text changes no problem. Only when it is called by an `event`

Comment: My initial thought was that the event was being triggered from a different thread, and that (likely) is the root of the issue.  Unity restricts its api execution to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

UI objects can only be changed from the main thread. If you are attempting to change a UI element from a different thread then it will not work. One possible solution is to use an IEnumerator ran in a Coroutine that waits until the Thread is completed and then update the UI element. Another option would be to look for updates periodically on the main Thread and then change the UI when a value is changed.